# Multiprogramming C++ Application For Every Frame

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, mfc, multiprocessing

Background: I am using C++ on Windows 10 with the MFC framework. I basically am taking a video and performing actions for every single frame of the video. For each frame of the video, I am creating a new text file and writing a bunch of data to the file, say 100 columns and 2000 rows of numbers. In my application, I also have a "Stop" button in order for the whole operation to be stopped.

I noticed that if I create the text file and write a bunch of data to it for EVERY SINGLE FRAME, I'm unable to even hit the "Stop" button. I'm assuming this is because the CPU is too busy writing to the text files, because if I only create a text file and write data to it EVERY 20 FRAMES (or around there), I'm able to hit "Stop" perfectly.

I need to be able to write data every single frame though. In terms of optimizing my program to be able to do that, I see 2 opportunities:

1. Multi-thread the writing of each text file for each frame
2. Have a separate thread/process waiting for the "Stop" button to be pressed so it can actually be pressed. (Is this possible?)

I just wanted to see if anyone else would have any other ideas on how I can achieve this. And are my assumptions/ideas correct?

Comment: Your assumptions are correct! But you only need to create a *single* separate thread to do the file-writing: that will have a loop, presumably, so you can set a mutex/flag in that loop to abort when it's signalled. Your main thread can then set that signal if the user clicks the "Stop" button.

Comment: Thanks for your response! To make sure I'm understanding correctly: so I would have a main thread which processes the entire application, waits for user actions, etc. Then, for EVERY frame, I would create a single separate thread to write to the file (or do you mean a single separate thread in total?). Inside the loop for writing to the file, I would have an if-check (if flag, then stop).

Comment: Just use *one* thread for writing the entire file: each iteration of the 'outer' loop (`for` if you know how many frames you have, or `while … EOF-check` if not) would first check the flag (abort if set) and then write that frame to the file.

Comment: Oh I see. In my case, I'm writing an individual file for every single frame. For instance, if I have 100 frames I would have 100 files in the end with data inside them. Also, I'm calling my function for writing to the file from a MESSAGE_MAP (from dll file) in MFC, so based on your idea, I would create a separate thread for that single fille-writing function? Sorry for the confusion, but appreciate your help so far!

Comment: Same logic: just create and write *each* file in *each* of the outer loops.

Comment: Sorry one more thing - and with that logic you stated, the whole piece is done by a single thread right? So, in total I have TWO threads for the entire functionality described above?

Comment: Correct: The main program thread, and the one created to write the file.

Comment: You can vastly improve readability and maintainability of your code by not fiddling with threads manually at all. Simply implement a coroutine (e.g. with a [fire_and_forget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/fire-and-forget) return type) to write the file, and move your input to it, either by value or using a `shared_ptr`. The system does the rest for you, like scheduling execution on the thread pool.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the suggestion! As far as I understand, coroutines are only available in C++20 right? I believe I'm using C++98, so I don't think I'd have that functionality available to me. Please correct me if I'm wrong though

Comment: Coroutines are a C++20 feature. Visual Studio supports them beginning with Visual Studio 2015. It is enabled using the [/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/await-enable-coroutine-support?view=vs-2019) compiler option.